# Yii2 - show rows in common between two tables

Tags: php, yii2

I Have two tables "Personal_data" and "Students", Student has Personal_data.
I used Gii to generate the code for views, controlers and models, and I need to show all "Personal_data" from "Students" in a GridView, but i cant get it.

Code from models/PersonalDataSearch.php

```
public function search($params)
{
    $query = PersonalData::find()->joinWith('Students'])->all();

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'id' => $this->id,
        'document' => $this->document,
        'telephone' => $this->telephone,
        'direction' => $this->direction,
        'sex' => $this->sex,
    ]);

    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'names', $this->names])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'lastNames', $this->lastNames])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'email', $this->email])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'movile', $this->movile]);

       return $dataProvider;
}
```

Code from controllers/PersonalDataController.php

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new PersonalDataSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

Code from views/personal-data/index.php

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        'names',
        'lastNames',
        'email:email',
        'movile',

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

This view originally show all rows from Personal_data table from all registered people, but I want just show Personal_Data from Students, I added this line:

```
$query = PersonalData::find()->joinWith('Students'])->all();
```

and I have this error:

> PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException
>
> Call to a member function andFilterWhere() on array

how can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `->all()` from

```
$query = PersonalData::find()->joinWith('Students'])->all();
```

Data provider is taking care of fetching the data from DB, you just need to build the query (`all()` is fetching the data). With just a query you can add filters to it so there will be no error for `andFilterWhere()`

Comment: Bizley you're right, remove all() method, solved the error, but the GridView still showing all rows from "PersonalData". After try over and over I added this:

$query = PersonalData::find()
->innerJoinWith('Students')
->where(['<>','Students.id','null']);

Now I get all "personal_data" from "Students", thank you.

Comment: Why not show the relation the other way around? students->personal_data.

Comment: I need to show some data in PersonalData and other in Students, but would be an option, thanks.